# WPF Fit window size

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new into WPF and i am developing a app with different images, textbox, etc. The problem is here on my screen it all looks ok according to the size of the window with the properties ive set on the window loaded:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
        Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
    }
```

When using the application on my screen it looks like this:

[image]

But when using it on a tablet i cant see the Calendar neither the text that says "Fecha nacimiento". Here is the WPF code i am using:

```
<Window x:Class="BiometricoRegistro.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="RegistrarCliente"  Height="978" Width="1600" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagenes\home_bg.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbRut" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="379" Margin="30,230,0,0" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold" PreviewTextInput="txtbRut_PreviewTextInput">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagenes\input.png"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbRutVer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Margin="430,230,0,0" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagenes\input.png"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbNombre" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" Margin="30,330,0,0" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagenes\input.png"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbApellido" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" Margin="30,430,0,0" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagenes\input.png"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbEmail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" Margin="30,530,0,0" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagenes\input.png"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
        <Calendar x:Name="calendar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Margin="0,720,0,57"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRegistrar" Content="Registrar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="118" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="296" Margin="775,0,221,100" Click="btnRegistrar_Click"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbPorcentaje" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="30,630,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="35">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="A" FontSize="35"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="B" FontSize="35"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="C" FontSize="35"></ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="30,176,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Rut cliente" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" FontFamily="/BiometricoRegistro;component/Fonts/#Alex Brush" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="30,286,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Nombres cliente" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" FontFamily="/BiometricoRegistro;component/Fonts/#Alex Brush" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="30,386,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Apellidos cliente" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" FontFamily="/BiometricoRegistro;component/Fonts/#Alex Brush" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="30,486,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email cliente" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" FontFamily="/BiometricoRegistro;component/Fonts/#Alex Brush" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="30,586,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tipo Descuento" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" FontFamily="/BiometricoRegistro;component/Fonts/#Alex Brush" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="30,678,0,230" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Fecha nacimiento" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" FontFamily="/BiometricoRegistro;component/Fonts/#Alex Brush" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="501,0,0,57" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="823" FontSize="46" Foreground="Red" FontFamily="PMingLiU-ExtB"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Controls positions of the your window are absolute so you can't see some of them on the tablet. You should make positions relative

Comment: Also add your grid inside a scrollViewer, you scroll down your controls.

Comment: You mean margins are absolute? because most of my controls are HorizontalAlignment="left" and VerticalAlignment="top" how i can make them relative?

Comment: @ffenix Try [using `RowDefinition`s and `ColumnDefinition`s](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html)?

Comment: @ffenix Yeah, margins are absolute. And also you put all controls in one `Grid`'s cell so you should use `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinition` as har07 said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Always use appropriate panels . I would prefer Dock and stackpanel with splitters.
2. assign System.Windows.Window.SizeToContent to System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight.
3. Use Resource Dictonary for consistency of margins and other values
4. I would not prefer to use Absolute positions. decide your margin values depending on your content .

Comment: Thank you i am using a dock panel now with stack panels inside